# URL path Redirection in Haproxy.cfg

Tags: haproxy

I have

```
https://www.mysites/v1/pages
```

and I want that to redirect to

```
https://www.mysites/v2/pages
```

I have added the following config on HAproxy config but not forward.

```
redirect location https://www.mysites/v2/pages 302 if { hdr(Host) mysites/v1/pages }
```

did I miss anything?

thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error message after saving the configuration and restarting HAProxy?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation for the [`redirect`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#4-redirect) statement makes me believe that part is correct (depending on where you put the statement).

Your ACL however doesn't seem to be correct. You filter on the host header (being www.mysites) while you should match on URI or [`path`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#7.3.6-path):

```
redirect location https://www.mysites/v2/pages 302 if { path_beg /mysites/v1/pages }
```